# Flow: does anything speak against using a flow and wait to create a workflow scheduler

Tags: visual-workflow, schedule

I have to live in a code-free world and really would like some scheduled actions.  What is the community feeling about using a Flow with a wait loop to exec actions weekly, monthly etc - I assume it's been tried and some of you folks will have opinions about reliability.

We're a small tenent and bound to code-free architecture regulations so I'm not concerned about performance or a little pain for maintainability.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I poked and prodded the 'infinite' loop approach a while ago, and it eventually will throw an error.

see : http://goravseth.com/infinite-flow-refined

Support logged it as a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YktAAE), in review for the past oh 2 years or so, dont anticipate it getting much attention.  I havent tested since then so its possible that the behavior is different now.

Instead of this I suggest checking out Doug Ayers' '[process builder scheduler](https://douglascayers.com/2016/04/18/salesforce-process-builder-scheduler/)' which uses scheduled apex to trigger flows via a custom object.  Its pretty crafty, and I think will be much more reliable in the long run.  Doesnt require you to write any code, but your environment will no longer be 100% code free.

Comment: Thanks very much (again) - I implemented this tonight.  Seems to be perfect for my above use-case.

Comment: You can do this without Apex. Use a record with a datetime field. When Flow ends have it create a new record Xminutes, hours, days, etc from current datetime. When you create this record create it so it has the attributes to trigger a Process. This record will now be sitting in scheduled actions waiting to fire. We have this run every 15 min 24X7. Little different approach than what Doug has

Answer (score 0):

You can use the infinite time-based workflow or process builder approach. As a workflow rule, you create two rules. Rule #1 triggers on a custom field being specified to a specific value, and sets a time-based delay that includes your custom action and a field update to a different specific value. Rule #2 triggers on a custom field being set to the different specific value, and sets the custom field to a specific value to trigger Rule #1. You can build the same sort of logic in a Process Builder. In both cases, make sure that the rule or process builder causes reevaluation of rules so it can run recursively. Either technique requires no code.

Comment: thanks - in your experience did you hit the same problems gorav had below, failure at a certain level of executions/loop iterations?

Comment: @AshleyEvans The bug is exclusive to Flows with Waits. Using Process Builder or Workflow Rules should provide viable alternatives. I tested this a long time ago (like, 8'ish years ago), but my understanding is that it still works.

Comment: great- thanks @sfdcfox - I opted for the Doug Ayers solution and hence marked that answer as "correct" because I felt that although it was technically code-based - there's very low maintainability risk and I didn't actually dev the code in-house or pay for it.  Seems like an architecturally elegant solution.  Thanks also very much for your feedback.